# Harsh colour banding in radial CGGradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-graphics

`CGContextDrawRadialGradient` produces a very visible ‘cross’ at the centre of the gradient:

[image: A visible radial cross at the gradient centre]

Code (reduced):

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

    size_t numberOfGradientLocations = 2;
    CGFloat startRadius = 0.0f;
    CGFloat endRadius = 30.0f;
    CGPoint centre = CGPointMake(floorf(self.bounds.size.width / 2), floorf(self.bounds.size.height / 2));
    CGFloat gradientColours[8] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    CGFloat gradientLocations[2] = {0.0f, 1.0f};

    CGColorSpaceRef colourspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colourspace, gradientColours, gradientLocations, numberOfGradientLocations);
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, centre, startRadius, centre, endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);
}
```

This happens on both macOS and iOS. Meanwhile, the same kind of gradient renders perfectly in WebKit with CSS (so it’s not some ‘bad display’ issue).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a known way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I get on iOS; I used the iPhone 7 Plus simulator at 100% so as to make every pixel visible, and it seems completely smooth:

[image]

**EDIT** After some experimentation, I suspect you're seeing a moiré effect caused by misalignment between points and pixels.

Comment: Interestingly, on a simulated iPad Air 2 I get pretty close to this. But not on iPad 2. And not on the macOS, also.

Comment: Oh! You're probably talking about a moiré effect.

Comment: Might be an effect of fading to transparent. Try fading from solid black to solid white instead and see if that helps. Also use grayscale color space instead of RGB.

Comment: Black-to-white gradient with no alpha renders practically the same. And DeviceGray is where I started (switched to RGB in hope that’d fix it) – still the same.

Comment: It does look like moiré (hence a specific cross pattern). But why only in Quartz, and not in WebKit?

Comment: Don't know, but moiré is typically caused by scaling down I believe.

Comment: Well, I’m positive I don’t scale it anywhere.

Comment: No, but it's suggestive (somehow) that the issue seems to arise specifically on single-resolution devices.

Comment: You’re right, it only seems to be a problem on single-resolution devices. I was wrong about Quartz being mindful of scale factor. Thanks, that was a valuable insight.

Comment: Another thing to watch for is rounding errors caused by odd numbers. Suppose your view is 99 pixels square. Then the bounds center is at `49.5`. Clearly we're heading for disaster as we try to paint the gradient from there. Such mismatch between points and pixels can happen in various ways. The Simulator will mark this with Color Misaligned Images in yellow, and I notice that the situations in which the yellow appears are exactly the situations in which I see the moiré effect. There must be a similar analysis tool for OS X.

Comment: Yes, I’m experimenting with alignment right now, and it seems to be the real issue. In this particular case, it’s the radius, but generally speaking, you’ve just given the right answer. Would you post it as such so I can accept it? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the radius. Clearly an even radius starting at an exact pixel boundary could be desirable. I did modify my answer to include the notion of misaligned images.